# Can I change a Kendo UI Grid's foreign key values?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid, foreign-keys

I have a Kendo grid that uses a drop down of foreign key values.  I need to be able to update these foreign key values based on the value of an external drop down on my page.  I am able to set the drop down's new values with Javascript, but the grid itself has the old values in that foreign key column.  I need to be able to set those values as well so the drop down works in edit mode.  Has anyone attempted to do this or seen an example of doing this?  I have searched a ton for this and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/text-in-grid-not-being-updated-when-selecting-from-dropdown),

```
function onGridEdit(e){
    var ddl = e.container.find("[data-role='dropdownlist']");
    if(ddl){
        ddl.getKendoDropDownList().bind("change", function(evt){
        e.model.set("ProductData.ProductValue.MasterDataText", this.text());
        });
    }
},
```

Alternatively, then you define drop down as an editor for a grid column, you can
do like this:

```
var customDdlEditor = function (container, options) {
    //some code...
    change: function (e) {
        options.model.Name = this.value();
    }, 
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem by loading the grid's foreign key values with all the values that can be set and then updating the pop up drop down with the new values on grid edit.  That way the drop down always has a value to bind to when edited in the grid.